# Clearing input element in mobile safari with javascript does not clear the ios autocorrect buffer

Tags: javascript, html, ios, mobile-safari, autocorrect

I have an `<input type="text">` element. The user types a string and hits enter which clears the element via `$('input').val('')`. The problem apparently is that iOS still has the previous input string in its autocorrect buffer, so when you begin to type a new word and hit space, it sees the last word from the previous string and the first word from the new string as one 'word' and attempts to autocorrect it. Example:

message1: `hello there`

message2: `well hi neighbor`

iOS sees: `therewell` on messages2 and autocorrects to `wellthere well`

another example:

message1: `hello moto`

message2: `boat`

autocorrects to `boatmotorboat` where `motorboat` is the autocorrected version of `motoboat` (combination of `moto` from the first message and `boat` from the second.

I realize this may just be a bug in mobile safari and I should just disable autocorrect on the input but perhaps there is a better solution?

Comment: The year is 2022 an this is still an issue in Safari. It seems humans will get to visit Mars before this gets fixed.