# iOS HTML autocorrect - save previous value after programmaticaly textarea clean

Tags: javascript, ios, html, textarea

I have a trouble with iOS HTML5 autocorrect. It's reproduced by JSBin http://jsbin.com/zusahev

```
// click - textarea loses focus - keyboard is closed
b1.addEventListener("click", function() {
  t1.value = '';
});

// touchend with preventDefault to save textarea focus
// but iOS autocorrect doesn't update current word
// how to manually trigger autocorrect update?
b2.addEventListener("touchend", function(e) {
  t2.value = '';
  e.preventDefault();
});
```

1. Open example in any iOS device
2. Enter text in the first textarea, click Button 1. Textarea loses focus
3. Enter text in the second textarea, click Button 2. Textarea doesn't lose focus, but iOS autocorrect doesn't update own value.

I expect that after change value in textarea autocorrect suggest would be updated. How to manually trigger autocorrect update?

[image: problem illustration]

Comment: Duplicate [Clearing input element in mobile safari with javascript does not clear the ios autocorrect buffer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18689842/clearing-input-element-in-mobile-safari-with-javascript-does-not-clear-the-ios-a)

Answer (score 0):

My solution is to allow textarea to lose its focus, and then focus on it again: http://output.jsbin.com/sihufuzigo

```
b2.addEventListener("click", function(e) {
  t2.value = '';
  t2.focus();
});
```

Note that iOS has limited the ability to `focus()` on fields programmatically: it could be done only from event handlers which are triggered by real user (real "click" event in this case) - see [Mobile Safari: Javascript focus() method on inputfield only works with click?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/12204571/1235394) for more information

Comment: This solution is not working for me. If I do this, the keyboard will stay open and the autocorrect will not be reset. Is still still working for you now?

Comment: @Tafel I cannot check, I have no iPhone anymore

Answer (score 0):

It turned out that this is very easy to solve.

**Step 1:** Create a secondary input and place it outside the screen with 0 width, 0 height

**Step 2:** On touchEnd do preventDefault and clear contenteditable

**Step 3:** Move the focus to the secondary input, and then back to the main one.

As a result, this will force the keyboard to recalculate the adjustment options and you will see the correct options.